# Android 6.0 Marshmallow How disable/hide Navigationbar/SystemUI

Tags: android, user-interface, android-6.0-marshmallow

[Navigationbar][1]

I'm writting an Application and in onCreate()-Function i'm disable the navigationbar:

In Android 4.4:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/xbin/su -c service call activity 42 s16 com.android.systemui");
```

In Android 5:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/xbin/su -c am stopservice -n com.android.systemui/.SystemUIService");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pm disable com.android.systemui");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("kill 'processID of systemui'");
```

This works fine.
But both doesn't works in Android 6.

after...

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/xbin/su -c service call activity 42 s16 com.android.systemui");
```

...the SystemUI/Navigationbar is disabled but also the Touch.

And after...

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/xbin/su -c am stopservice -n com.android.systemui/.SystemUIService");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pm disable com.android.systemui");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("kill 'processID of systemui'");
```

... the SystemUI/Navigation is disabled for 3 seconds and then it appears again.

Can anybody Help?

Comment: You are set the programmatically to logic for 3 second more about detail see this link:-https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html

Comment: This worked for me (android 6.0.1) https://stackoverflow.com/a/41856988/3547724

Answer (score 1):

I am still looking for a convenient answer for this issue, but for the moment I use :

Disable status bar

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("settings put global device_provisioned 0");
```

Enable status bar

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("settings put global device_provisioned 1");
```

That is not perfect, but htat is a first step.

Comment: Did you find a solution? The above solution does not work for me :(