# Removing Android navigation and topbar,

Tags: java, android, kiosk-mode

I am trying to implement a Kiosk app on a rooted android device, and I need to disable the navigation and status bar completely.

These commands works from adb shell

Disable:

```
service call activity 42 s16 com.android.systemui
```

Enable:

```
am startservice -n com.android.systemui/.SystemUIService
```

That's good! Now I need to be able to do it from my app. So to disable I've tried:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su service call activity 42 s16 com.android.systemui");
```

when pressing a button in my activity. But nothing happens, and no exceptions are thrown. A toast pops up though, saying that the app has been given super user rights.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To run su cmd you can use this

```
public static void runCmd(String cmd) {
    DataOutputStream os;
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
        os.writeBytes(cmd + "\n");
        os.writeBytes("exit\n");
        os.flush();
        os.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

To disable system ui you can run this command

```
runCmd("pm disable com.android.systemui && service call activity 42 s16 com.android.systemui");
```

If you want to enable back

```
runCmd("pm enable com.android.systemui && am startservice -n com.android.systemui/.SystemUIService");
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! THANKS!

Comment: When I run this command, navigation bar disapears but I cannot touch the screen anymore

Comment: @alexislg Did you solve this non-touchable screen problem? Can't make it work on API 23+ (Marshmallow)...

Comment: @GergelyKőrössy yes. I use `settings put secure user_setup_complete 0`

Answer (score 4):

With Android 5 and 6, you can try this trick:

```
settings put secure user_setup_complete 0
```

Comment: This does not remove the navigation bar only disables the home button.

Comment: On my device it removes everything. My app is in immersive mode

Comment: Oh, I see it now. I thought it would work just like `service call activity ...` did.

Answer (score 0):

Split su call and command call :

```
try{
    Process su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(su.getOutputStream());

    outputStream.writeBytes("service call activity 42 s16 com.android.systemui");
    outputStream.flush();

    outputStream.writeBytes("exit\n");
    outputStream.flush();
    su.waitFor();
}catch(IOException e){
    throw new Exception(e);
}catch(InterruptedException e){
    throw new Exception(e);
}
```